# How to find the nlargest from a large csv file using pandas (chunked)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a very large csv file with many rows and 3 columns:

the file is read as following :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep=" ", chunksize=100000)
```

Now how to get the N largest rows based on the values in the 3rd column when chunkzise is utilized ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get top 5 values from pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462690/how-to-get-top-5-values-from-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get first and second highest values in pandas columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39066260/6045800)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(df.nlargest(N, columns=df.columns[2]))
```

Comment: @Win It should I guess, you should try, remember to accept and upvote if it helps

Comment: dosent work, it gives "AttributeError: 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'nlargest' "