# Pandas : Top N results with float and string list

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

```
idx float str+list
1   -0.2  [A,B]
1   -0.1  [A,D]
1    0.2  [B,C]
```

To know the best result :
`df.loc[df['float'].idxmax()]['str+list']`

**How can I have the top 2 idxmax results?**

nlargest gives me error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get top 5 values from pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462690/how-to-get-top-5-values-from-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: partially but that's not the exact answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html):

```
s = df.nlargest(2, 'float')['str+list']
print (s)
2    [B,C]
1    [A,D]
Name: str+list, dtype: object
```

Or sorting with select top N values:

```
df.sort_values('float', ascending=False)['str+list'].head(2)
```